# How to generate constant name quoted with double-quote with grunt-ng-constant

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm using [grunt-ng-constant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-constant) to generate my `config.js`.

I've configured the [default serializer](https://github.com/rlidwka/jju), through the [`serializerOptions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ng-constant#optionsserializeroptions) option, to use the [double quote](https://github.com/rlidwka/jju#jjustringify-function) as enquoting char:

```
ngconstant: {
  // Options for all targets
  options: {
    space: '  ',
    wrap: '"use strict";\n\n {%= __ngModule %}',
    name: 'config',
    serializerOptions: {quote:'"'}
},
```

The generated `config.js` file looks like this:

```
angular.module('config', [])
.constant('env', {name: "development"})
```

The problem is that the constant names and the module name are quoted with single quote char.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be to provide a different template for config generation.

The [default template](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant/blob/master/tasks/constant.tpl.ejs) is:

```
angular.module('{%- moduleName %}'{% if (deps) { %}, [{%= deps.map(function (name) { return '\'' + name + '\'' }).join(', ') %}]{% } %})
{% constants.forEach(function (constant) { %}
.constant('{%- constant.name %}', {%= constant.value %})
{% }); values.forEach(function (value) { %}
.value('{%- value.name %}', {%= value.value %})
{% }) %}
;
```

It should be changed in:

```
angular.module("{%- moduleName %}"{% if (deps) { %}, [{%= deps.map(function (name) { return '"' + name + '"' }).join(', ') %}]{% } %})
{% constants.forEach(function (constant) { %}
.constant("{%- constant.name %}", {%= constant.value %})
{% }); values.forEach(function (value) { %}
.value('{%- value.name %}', {%= value.value %})
{% }) %}
;
```